# Ascending ringtone volume in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ringtones

It was driving me crazy that every time someone was calling to my iPhone it started ringing at full volume when most of the times I would even hear it with a simple vibration because I always have it right next to me.

So how can I get a ringtone with ascending volume onto my iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Requirements**

- GarageBand application for the iPhone (free)

**Solution**

1. Download the ringtone file to iCloud. Just click [this link](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0KTJTIBT8ecEJfcmnBPty5_Tw#Opening_(Gradual)) and then "Add to iCloud Drive"

   [image: Uploading ringtone to iCloud]
2. Open **GarageBand** application in your phone, click the import button and look for the ringtone file in the iCloud folder, don't open it, just long press it and then click on the share option.

   [image]
3. Select the **ringtone** option and then click Export in the top right corner. Finally when exported, click the option **"Use sound as..."** and then **"Standard Ringtone"**. Done!
4. Now you can delete GarageBand application if you want, it takes a lot of space (1.77 GB).

**Notes:**

If you want to make any modification to the fade effect you will need to open [this folder](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_Bcn7I4Vg_HwT8BK_wFQxSvYFrqXwECu) in a Mac with GarageBand, change the Master Track, and then go to **Share > Project to GarageBand for iOS**.

You can inspire in that file to make any ringtone increment the volume gradually.

**Update**

Updated links:
[Opening (Gradual)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dOtm46I4Uh7ZAum5yDKrVpnFrRMJAGhm?usp=sharing)
[Opening (Gradual) for Mac](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_Bcn7I4Vg_HwT8BK_wFQxSvYFrqXwECu?usp=sharing)

PD: I don't own an iPhone anymore and don't know if this method still works

Comment: Instead of just posting the resulting audio track could you describe in more details what you actually did in GarageBand to create it?

Comment: Sure! To modify the fade of any audio you just need to have the audio file (in this case, opening ringtone, I downloaded it online). Then you open it with GarageBand for mac, next you just click on the menu option Track > Show master and edit the yellow line that is the volume throughout the time.
To edit mine just check out the notes in my answer, show the Master Track and start playing with it.

Comment: Does this also work with GB on the iPhone alone or is this only possible in GB for Mac?

Comment: To make a custom ringtone you will need the GB for Mac, there is not the needed option in the GB for iPhone. But if you just want the regular ringtone it should be enough with the GB for the iPhone and the file linked in the answer.

Comment: Obviously this is _NOT_ the solution but limited _workaround_ rather because it would play the track in _loop_ mode so it means effectively you'd need to write track _long enough (say, 5 minutes)_ to lower the chances you'll get low volume during playback exactly then when you'd hear it be it louder

Comment: Actually when someone calls you the phone sounds for something around 30 seconds, and this ringtone is 30 seconds long, so finally you don't ear it repeating itself.

Comment: Could you please share the file again?

Comment: Sorry for the very long response @Orbit , I just updated the post with some new links